# Is it possible to find keys which are on different shards using Lettuce using Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am using Spring Data Redis in my API. I am trying run the following command through Java:

```
Set<String> union = redisTemplate.opsForSet().union(ids);
```

which is causing CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot err since keys I am searching are on different shards.

My Redis db model is having SET datamodel for keys which I am trying to find.

Is there any way Lettuce can find keys across shards and I can avoid this err. My LettuceConnectionFactory is as it is:

```
@Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(port);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(host);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(database);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(password)) redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(password);

        LettuceClientConfiguration.LettuceClientConfigurationBuilder builder = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder();
        if (useSSl) {
            builder.useSsl();
        }

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = builder
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisTimeoutMillis))
                .clientOptions(ClientOptions
                        .builder()
                        .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                        .build())
                .build();

        LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfiguration);
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

Also, is it possible to avoid union operation and use org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository findAllByIds(ids) to get the same output?

Comment: Do you mean by keys in your context? Question is not clear. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Yes, is there any way we can avoid the cross slot err with Lettuce?

Comment: Yes! Providing my answer. Just writing the answer at this moment.

Comment: Can you please provide minimum example codebase via github to understand the issue in depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a lot, I've found some info on why you are facing this **CROSSSLOT** error with **Redis**.

There is a good explanatory blog [here](https://www.dragonflydb.io/error-solutions/crossslot-keys-in-request-dont-hash-to-the-same-slot) on CROSSSLOT KEYS issue. Please read it.

From that blog, the following things can be concluded.

**Reason of the error:**

> This error occurs when you try to perform an operation that involves
> multiple keys in a Redis Cluster, but those keys do not belong to the
> same hash slot.

**Possible solutions suggested that you can take to mitigate the issue:**

- Use a **single-node configuration** if there is no needed for scalability (provided by Redis Cluster). This will make sure all the keys are in a single node and thereby eliminating the issue of CROSSSLOT Keys completely.
- Optimize your entity model to reduce the need for multi-key operations as Redis will be unable to maintain this.
- You can use tag within the key. **Advantage:** Let's say if you have multiple keys and now you attach them with the same tag, then this will make sure that multiple keys are going into the same hashed slot, thereby reducing the cross-slot operation.

**Read the blog for information.**

---

**Follow these Github issues given below for reference:**

- [CROSSSLOT error with Spring Oauth2 (version 2.3.0.RELEASE) [DATAREDIS-1154]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/1727)
- [CROSSSLOT error on single-shard cluster](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/5118)

First of all, don't get mislead with the use of keyword 'Spring OAuth2'. The issue is the same as that you are facing.

Note: **Slot != Shard**

The main thing I want to mention is multiple hashed slots are getting created by keys within the shard and getting them from multiple slots by cross operation is not allowed.

Now, I guess most probably you are using single node configuration by looking at your code. So, please stop running cluster mode for redis.

---

Now, coming to this question

> Also, is it possible to avoid union operation and use
> org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository findAllByIds(ids)
> to get the same output?

Yes, it's possible to achieve via **Redis-OM for Spring** library and **Redis Stack Server** which comes with enhanced features for [**Search and Query**](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/).

Official [Redis-OM Docs](https://developer.redis.com/develop/java/spring/redis-om/redis-om-spring) says:

> Redis OM Spring provides powerful repository and custom object-mapping
> abstractions built on top of the amazing **Spring Data Redis** (SDR)
> framework.

Now, step - by - step process:

1. Download **Redis Stack** from [here](https://redis.io/download/#redis-stack-downloads) based on the OS.
2. Extract the downloaded zip and go into bin folder of redis stack and run the executable file **redis-stack-server**.

**Note:** I'm using **macOS**, **Java 17**, **Spring Boot 2.7.x** and **Redis 7.2.1** to demonstrate this.

3. Open two terminals and run the **redis-stack-server** file and **redis-cli** file on each terminal respectively.
4. Now, in CLI mode, Enter the command `MONITOR`. to start tracking any activities happening on the redis server.
5. Coming to codebase:

I took help of their [Redis-OM Spring tutorial for hashes](https://developer.redis.com/develop/java/spring/redis-om/redis-om-spring-hash) for reference.

You will need to include `redis-om-spring` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` as dependencies in **POM**.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-redis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-redis-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.redis.om</groupId>
            <artifactId>redis-om-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Startup class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisEnhancedRepositories
public class TestRedisSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestRedisSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

You have to use `@EnableRedisEnhancedRepositories` to detect presence of the repositories using redis - based model.

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

Entity class :

```
import com.redis.om.spring.annotations.Indexed;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

@Data
@RedisHash
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NonNull
    @Indexed
    private String fullName;

    @NonNull
    @Indexed
    private String job;
}
```

**Note:** `@RedisHash`, `@Indexed` are annotations from Redis-OM lib and it works with Redis Stack Server as it has extensive support for searching and querying which normal Redis Server lacks.

Custom Redis Configuration which takes guarantee of creating bean of `JedisConnectionFactory` and thereby providing it to the **Redis-OM** and it's mandatory to supply that bean.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConf.setHostName("localhost");
        redisConf.setPort(6379);
        JedisClientConfiguration conf = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .build();
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConf, conf);
    }

}
```

Controller Code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("save")
    public Person save(@RequestBody Person p) {
        return repository.save(p);
    }

    @GetMapping("/find-all-by-ids")
    public List<Person> getAllPersonByIds(@RequestBody List<String> pids) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAllById(pids).forEach(list::add);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The server start successfully.

**Logs:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64359:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anish/Downloads/test-redis-spring/target/classes:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-data-redis-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.12/logback-classic-1.2.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.12/logback-core-1.2.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.36/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.30/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.7.16/spring-data-redis-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-keyvalue/2.7.16/spring-data-keyvalue-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.7.16/spring-data-commons-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.30/spring-tx-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-oxm/5.3.30/spring-oxm-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.30/spring-aop-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/5.3.30/spring-context-support-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/lettuce/lettuce-core/6.1.10.RELEASE/lettuce-core-6.1.10.RELEASE.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.97.Final/netty-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.97.Final/netty-handler-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.97.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.97.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.97.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.97.Final/netty-codec-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.97.Final/netty-transport-4.1.97.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.4.32/reactor-core-3.4.32.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.4/reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.5/jackson-databind-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.5/jackson-annotations-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.5/jackson-core-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.5/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.5/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.80/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.80.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.80/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.80.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.80/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.80.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.30/spring-web-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.30/spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.30/spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.30/spring-context-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.30/spring-expression-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/redis/om/redis-om-spring/0.6.0/redis-om-spring-0.6.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.7.16/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.16/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/redislabs/jrejson/1.5.0/jrejson-1.5.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/redis/clients/jedis/3.8.0/jedis-3.8.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.11.1/commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/redislabs/jredisearch/2.2.0/jredisearch-2.2.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20210307/json-20210307.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/redislabs/jrebloom/2.2.0/jrebloom-2.2.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-jre/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.12.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/github/f4b6a3/ulid-creator/5.0.1/ulid-creator-5.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/squareup/javapoet/1.13.0/javapoet-1.13.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.7.16/spring-boot-devtools-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.16/spring-boot-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/2.7.16/spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.7.16.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.30/lombok-1.18.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.30/spring-core-5.3.30.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.30/spring-jcl-5.3.30.jar com.example.testredis.TestRedisSpringApplication
17:26:44.447 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@7f476533

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.16)

2023-09-30 17:26:44.842  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.TestRedisSpringApplication         : Starting TestRedisSpringApplication using Java 17.0.8 on Anishs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 27499 (/Users/anish/Downloads/test-redis-spring/target/classes started by anish in /Users/anish/Downloads/test-redis-spring)
2023-09-30 17:26:44.843  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.TestRedisSpringApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-30 17:26:44.917  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-30 17:26:44.917  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-09-30 17:26:45.425  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-09-30 17:26:45.425  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-30 17:26:45.597  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 159 ms. Found 1 Redis repository interfaces.
2023-09-30 17:26:46.004  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.redis.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration' of type [com.redis.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.009  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customRedisConfiguration' of type [com.example.testredis.CustomRedisConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5edc0326] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.052  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jedisConnectionFactory' of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.127  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'redisTemplate' of type [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.135  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'redisModulesClient' of type [com.redis.om.spring.client.RedisModulesClient] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.137  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'redisModulesOperations' of type [com.redis.om.spring.ops.RedisModulesOperations] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.138  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'keyspaceToIndexMap' of type [com.redis.om.spring.KeyspaceToIndexMap] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.715  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-30 17:26:46.727  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-30 17:26:46.728  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.80]
2023-09-30 17:26:46.811  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-30 17:26:46.812  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1894 ms
2023-09-30 17:26:47.040  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-09-30 17:26:47.720  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-30 17:26:47.727  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : Creating Indexes......
2023-09-30 17:26:47.735  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : Found 0 @Document annotated Beans...
2023-09-30 17:26:47.741  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : Found 1 @RedisHash annotated Beans...
2023-09-30 17:26:47.741  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : Found @RedisHash annotated class: com.example.testredis.Person
2023-09-30 17:26:47.742  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : FOUND @Indexed annotation on field of type: class java.lang.String
2023-09-30 17:26:47.743  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.r.om.spring.RedisModulesConfiguration  : FOUND @Indexed annotation on field of type: class java.lang.String
2023-09-30 17:26:47.792  INFO 27499 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.t.TestRedisSpringApplication         : Started TestRedisSpringApplication in 3.335 seconds (JVM running for 3.879)
2023-09-30 19:12:53.073  INFO 27499 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-30 19:12:53.074  INFO 27499 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-30 19:12:53.086  INFO 27499 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
```

I'm creating two data in redis by using the endpoint : `http://localhost:8080/person/save`

Screenshot:

[image]

Redis CLI logs:

[image]

Now, I will try to get the data from getAllById endpoint: http://localhost:8080/person/find-all-by-ids

Screenshot:[image]

Redis CLI logs:

[image]

That's all.

Comment: Hi Anish, thanks for such a detail answer. I did not try Redis OM since they say it is still not ready until we have 1.0.0 version, https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring. Another solutions: 1) Use all individual nodes while connecting to redis not using only single URL 2) Change underneath redis data model not to use Set. 3) Try converting redis cluster to a single node (which I cannot do bcz a separate infra team is not allowing). So, I am going for second solution. But thanks a lot.